# Error deploying ASP.NET MVC application to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am deploying my first ASP.NET MVC to Windows Azure. After deploying the site is working and also the links within. But hours later if I check the links again it shows the following error:

> An error occurred while processing your request.

I used the steps mentioned [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Any idea what I am missing? Why is it working for hours and then throwing an error?

Comment: The connection string is correct on azure ?

Comment: I think yes, because it worked for hours.

Comment: It is an exception you don't catch and Azure won't display it for security reasons, see this tutorial about ASP.NET Azure troubleshooting: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/

Answer (score 3):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is the quick-and-dirty approach but it will at least get you the information you are looking for. Just be sure to turn custom errors back on when you are done. NOTE: This method will display your stacktrace to the entire world.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC this error will show if any exception will occur. You need to debug your code via enabling trace logs or by changing parameter in web.config file so it will display the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for getting the error details and debugging.

1) Diagnostic  configuration for web role. Enable application error. So the application error will be logged to the WADEventTable.Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx

2) While deploying/publishing the application, Enable the remote desktop for role. So basically it will you can connect to role instance remotely and see in event viewer

3) Define custom page in the application and redirect to it with exception details